# No way to set protobuf element by copyin instead of set_allocated_something?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

On my generated protobuf classes, I see only `set_allocated_something`.

Example:

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "uuid.proto";
import "openvpn.proto";
package message;

message VPN {
    UUID uuid = 1;
    oneof vpn {
        OpenVPN openVPN = 2;
    }
}
```

then I have:

```
OpenVPN openVPN;
//fill openVPN
auto vpnAny = someObject.add_vpns();
vpnAny->set_allocated_openvpn(&openVPN);
```

The following code crashes because I'm adding an object for which I own the data, and then `set_allocated_openvpn` is going to delete it first, then the scope is going to delete it a second time.

The alternative would be to do

```
OpenVPN* openVPN = new OpenVPN();
```

but I want to avoid raw pointers + `new`.

Why simply won't protobuf generate a method that copies the data? Why I can only pass allocated data pointer? And how should I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobuf generates copy constructors and copy assignment operators for every type. So the most normal way to copy a message into another would be something like

```
OpenVPN openVPN;
// (...)
*someObject.add_vpns() = openVPN;
```